# Проверить, есть ли значение в массиве PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется класс FilmInfo

```
class FilmInfo extends Film
{
    public $actors=array();
    public $categories=array();
    public $language;

    public function __construct($id, $title, $description, $releaseYear, $length, $actors, $categories, $language)
    {
        parent::__construct($id, $title, $description, $releaseYear, $length);
        $this->actors=$actors;
        $this->categories=$categories;
        $this->language=$language;
    }
}
```

Так как у фильма может быть несколько жанров, то категории являются массивом

Пытаюсь вывести фильмы, у которых категория равна 1

```
                <?php
                    $db=new PDOService();
                    foreach ($db->getAllFilmsInfo() as $film) {
                        if (array_key_exists(1, $film->categories)) {
                            echo $film->id." ".$film->title."<br />";
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

Но выводит только 1 фильм из 4.

Comment: array_key_exists ищу по ключу. Выполняю в foreach, значит должно несколько фильмов вывестись, у которых ключ категории равен 1... Но что-то не так

Comment: массив не может содержать несколько элементов с одним ключом

Comment: Кстати, для читабельности можно первый if развернуть: 
`if (!$this->connect()) { return $films;}` было бы симпатичнее. Данные и связи лучше нормализовать. Хранить информацию и фильме, аля `category = 1,2,3,4,5,6` и потом эксплоидить это -- неблагодарное дело. Я когда-то использовал подобный подход, потом страдал.

Comment: негоже открывать и закрывать коннект к БД при каждом запросе...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_key_exists` ищет по ключу массива, но ключи вы не указываете внутри `$categories[]=new Category($category[0], $category[1]);`, следовательно все ключи всегда будут 0, 1, 2... в зависимости от кол-ва элементов.

Если я вас правильно понял, то надо проверить есть ли в массиве категория, у которой Id равен 1. В таком случае надо проверять не наличие ключа, а наличие элемента с параметром Id=1. Для удобства добавим метод `hasCategory` в класс `FilmInfo`:

```
public function hasCategory(int $id) : bool {
  foreach($this->categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->getId() == $id) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

После чего вместо `array_key_exists(1,...)` пропишем

```
if ($film->hasCategory(1)) {
  echo $film->id, ' ', $film->title, '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ! Он очень помог разобраться. Ещё раз спасибо.